# Centering a fixed size canvas in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm in the process of creating a circuit editor (similar to any regular paint software with a basic menu and a canvas with specifiable dimensions). I am currently trying to transform the previously unscrollable canvas (`JPanel`) to a scrollable one.

[image: Circuit Editor]

The obvious design error at the moment is that while the scrollbars seem to correctly reflect the internal size of the canvas (which can of course be way bigger than the `JFrame`), due to the canvas `JPanel` being added in the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout` of the master panel, it always resizes along with the `JFrame`.

```
public final class MainFrame extends JFrame 
{
    public MainFrame()
    {            
        JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        // Populate Menu Panel
        // ...

        JPanel canvasPanel = new JPanel();
        canvasPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        Dimension canvasDims = new Dimension(800,600);        
        canvasPanel.setPreferredSize(canvasDims);
        canvasPanel.setMinimumSize(canvasDims);
        canvasPanel.setMaximumSize(canvasDims);

        JScrollPane canvasScrollPane = new JScrollPane(
            canvasPanel,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        masterPanel.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        masterPanel.add(canvasScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setContentPane(masterPanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1200, 700);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true); 
    }
```

I've read quite a few posts regarding centering JPanels and scrollbars but with both complexities added together, things might be a bit more complicated as I haven't yet found a solution.

What I'm really trying to achieve is to have the canvas' `JPanel` fixed in whatever size the user might have specified and centered in the middle as well as the scrollbars behaving as one would expect like in the beloved windows' paint:

[image]

How would you go about doing this/fixing my design? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Happy new Year :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JPanel fixed in whatever size the user might have specified and centered in the middle as well as the scrollbars behaving as one would expect

So you need to nest panels so the canvas panel can be displayed at its preferred size, while the parent panel resizes with the size of the frame.

An easy way to do this is with a `JPanel` that uses a `GridBagLayout`. Then you add the canvas panel to this panel using the default `GridBagConstraints`.

So the basic structure of the panels would be:

```
JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
canvas.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 300) );
canvas.setBackground(Color.RED);

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
wrapper.add(canvas, new GridBagConstraints() );

frame.add(new JScrollPane(wrapper));
```

Note: there is no need for your "masterPanel". The default layout manager for the content pane of a `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout`, so you just add the "menuPanel" and "scrollPane" directly to the frame with the proper `BorderLayout` constraints.